# run golang gin api project using aws lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I am tring to run my go project using amazon lambda, this is my current main.go

```
https://gist.github.com/krakiun/61e4e4dc5ab91f557e481f0230ed3ba0
```

I tried several methods, but none worked
How i can make run this project in lambda, in this moment if i run using `router.Run(cfg.HTTP.ListenAddr)` is working without any error,

with this `log.Fatal(gateway.ListenAndServe(cfg.HTTP.ListenAddr, router))` is die with this error :

```
expected AWS Lambda environment variables [_LAMBDA_SERVER_PORT AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API] are not defined
exit status 1
```

How i can fix my code to run in aws lambda ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the environment

the  below code for run at local

```
router.Run(cfg.HTTP.ListenAddr)
```

the lambda can only run on the AWS Lambda Function. You must deploy it to lambda

```
lambda.Start(router)
```

You can check the example at https://maxrohde.com/2021/05/01/lambda-go-starter-project/. And the source code is here: https://github.com/mxro/go-lambda-starter-project/tree/main/packages/lambda-go-gin